# How do I remove specific input in string

Tags: php

String : ID#6 Item name

I want to remove any `ID#1` or `ID#18` & keep the word after.

```
$string = str_replace('ID#', '', $string);
$string = substr(strstr("$string"," "), 1);
```

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: $str = 'ID#6 Item name';
echo preg_replace ( '/ID#\d+/' , '' , $str )

Comment: You'll need to use a regex. `str_replace` is for static content being replaced. Is it always a number after `ID#`?

Comment: @bassxzero +1 @chris85 yes.. always a number after `ID#`

Comment: Than @bassxzero comment should work for you. You can test regexs and see what they are doing on various sites for example regex101.com.

Comment: is the space after the number always there??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might look a bit weird, but its a one liner

```
$test = "ID#6123234235345asdasdasdasd";
var_dump(ltrim($test, "ID#0..9")); // string(12) "asdasdasdasd"
```